# Bit shifting c# what's going on here?

Tags: c#, endianness

So I'm curious, what exactly is going on here?

```
static void SetUInt16 (byte [] bytes, int offset, ushort val)
{
    bytes [offset] = (byte) ((val & 0x0ff00) >> 8);
    bytes [offset + 1] = (byte) (val & 0x0ff);
}
```

Basically the idea in this code is to set a 16 bit int into a byte buffer at a specific location, but the problem is I'm trying to emulate it using

```
using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
using(var w = new BinaryWriter(ms))
{
    w.Write((ushort)1);
}
```

I'm expecting to read `1` but instead I'm getting `256`. Is this an endianness issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code writes a 16-bit integer in big-endian order.  Upper byte is written first.  Not the same thing that BinaryWriter does, it writes in little-endian order.

Comment: That was what I was kind of assuming, just don't fully understand bitwise operations etc.

Comment: It is not a bit operation, just shuffling bytes here.  Skeet has written a bigendian writer class: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/

Comment: So I could just do then, `w.Write((byte) ((val & 0x0ff00) >> 8))` and then `w.Write((byte) (val & 0x0ff))` since it's just flipping them around?

Answer (score 3):

When you decode the data, are you getting 256 when you expect 1? [BinaryWriter.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sh9zw1e.aspx) uses little-endian encoding, your SetUInt16 method is using big-endian.